# does coroutines in Kotlin work like threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So I am trying to learn kotlin coroutines for networking purposes on Android but I don't understand how they work. What am I missing in the code to make it work like a thread (the two counters should mix together ) ? Should I use something else than runBlocking {} ?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun counter(a: Int) {
    for(n in 0..a) {
        print(n.toString() + " ")
    }
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        counter(10)
        launch {
            counter(10)
        }
    }
}
```

output : `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer to "does coroutines work like threads?". It really depends on the context. From some perspective you can say they work like threads, from other they do not.

In your specific case I would say: yes, they work similarly to threads. You can launch two coroutines, so they will work concurrently and in parallel and you will see logs mixed together. There are two reasons why you don't see this in your example.

First, you `launch()` your second coroutine only after the first already finished. You have to use `launch()` twice or reorder your code to `launch()` first and then do `counter()`:

```kotlin
launch {
    counter(10)
}
counter(10)
```

Second, `runBlocking()` is very special in a way that by default it creates a single-threaded dispatcher. That means coroutines could work concurrently, but not in parallel. You can compare this to spawning two threads on a single-core CPU - both threads will run eventually, however, they have to wait for each other.

There are two ways to fix this. You can use a multi-threaded dispatcher:

```kotlin
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    launch {
        counter(10)
    }
    counter(10)
}
```

Or you can keep using only a single thread, but make your coroutines cooperatively yield their thread for other coroutines:

```kotlin
for(n in 0..a) {
    print(n.toString() + " ")
    yield()
}
```

Alternatively, instead of `yield()` you can use `delay()` or suspend the execution in any other way.

Comment: Thank you I have a better understanding of it now !

Answer (score 0):

The subject you're talking about is called **Race Conditions**, which coroutines in Kotlin prevent that from happening.
I recommend you to take this quick official tutorial on Kotlin Coroutines by Google: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-introduction-coroutines

This will answer all your questions.

Comment: Thank you I will read that,! So the result I see doesn't mean the code is not executed asynchronously but that it's just the usual behaviour of coroutines ?

Comment: @KrySoar `runBlocking()`, which as the name implies, starts a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until completion. It is mainly used to bridge between blocking and non-blocking code in main functions and tests. You will not be using it often in typical Android code.

When used in the main thread, `runBlocking()` will stop the main thread until it finishes its work. It's not a good practice to use it since the whole concept of coroutines is to run code asynchronously.

Comment: @KrySoar Also, note that coroutines are just a wrapper for threads, to reduce the struggles of working with threads directly and their unexpected behaviors. They also save states, for example a coroutine can be paused and resumed on demand.

Comment: That's what I thought about `runBlocking()` but I don't know the other functions for coroutines so I tested with this,